# Can I override a scala class method with a method from a trait?

Tags: scala

```
class PasswordCaseClass(val password:String)
trait PasswordTrait { self:PasswordCaseClass =>
    override def password = "blue"
}

val o = new PasswordCaseClass("flowers") with PasswordTrait
```

Is it possible to override `PasswordCaseClass`'s `password` with what is provided in `PasswordTrait`? Right now, I receive this error:

```
e.scala:6: error: overriding value password in class PasswordCase
Class of type String;
 method password in trait PasswordTrait of type => java.lang.String needs to be a stable,
immutable value
val o = new PasswordCaseClass("flowers") with PasswordTrait
            ^
one error found
```

I would like to be able to have something like this:

```
class User(val password:String) {
}

trait EncryptedPassword { u:User =>
  def password = SomeCriptographyLibrary.encrypt(u.password)
}

val u = new User("random_password") with EncryptedPassword
println(u.password) // see the encrypted version here
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can override a `def` with a `val`, but you can't do it the other way around. A `val` implies a guarantee -- that it's value is stable and immutable -- that a `def` does not.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me (with some modifications):

```
trait PasswordLike {
 val password: String 
}

class PasswordCaseClass(val password:String) extends PasswordLike

trait PasswordTrait extends PasswordLike {
 override val password: String = "blue"
}
```

and then:

```
scala> val o = new PasswordCaseClass("flowers") with PasswordTrait
o: PasswordCaseClass with PasswordTrait = $anon$1@c2ccac

scala> o.password
res1: String = blue
```

Comment: But shouldn't Scala be indifferent if I'm using a field or a method?

Comment: Well, regarding to the overriding, I think that def can be overriden by val, but not reversely.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to override the value with the method definition. It simply makes no sense - they have different semantics. Values supposed to be calculated once per object lifecycle (and stored within a final class attribute) and methods can be calculated multiple times. So what you are trying to do is to brake the contract of the class in a number of ways.

Anyway there is also compiler's fault - the error explanation is totally unclear.

Comment: The error says that there is an error in the overriding of the *value* `password` with a *method* `password`: you must use an "stable, immutable value". Can't see why that's "totally unclear".

Comment: I think that the good explanation should be "Name collision between the val and the def declarations". Don't take it too seriously - it is just an opinion of not-a-compiler-expert.

Comment: I think that message is more confusing than the original, personally.

Comment: I think the existing error explanation is only unclear if you have not yet understood the distinction between a `val` and a `def` (or method).  Otherwise, it's _perfectly_ on target, far more so than something that claims a "name collision", because it (1) correctly identifies the problem, and (2) tells you that what you're trying is impossible (i.e. a val must be stable).