# Referencing the parent class inside a Trait

Tags: scala, overriding, mixins, traits

I have a class that extends a Trait and I want to write Traits that can mix in with the class and override some of the methods.

The trait that my class is extending looks like this

```
trait CharSource  {

    def source: Iterator[Char]
    def words: Iterator[String] = { 
        while(source.hasNext){
           //Logic to get the next word from a Char Iterator
        }
    }

    final def chars: Iterator[Char] = words.toString().toIterator
}
```

The class that extends CharSource

```
class IteratorDocumentSource(iterator: Iterator[Char]) extends CharSource {
   def source = iterator
}
```

Now I want to write a trait to override the source def in IteratorDocutmentSource for some special behavior

```
trait PunctuationRemover extends Transformer {self: CharSource =>
override

  /** Character source.  Overriding should be in terms of `super.source` for           
  stackability. */
  abstract val source: Iterator[Char] = {
    super.source
    //additional logic ...
  }
}
```

The transformer trait that PunctioationRemover extends

```
trait Transformer {self: CharSource =>

  protected def source: Iterator[Char]
  def words: Iterator[String]
}
```

I get an error when making this call

```
new IteratorDocumentSource("Hello World!".iterator) with PunctuationRemover
```

Error:

> An exception or error caused a run to abort:
>   SampleSuite$$anonfun$2$$anon$3.document$PunctuationRemover$$super$source()Lscala/collection/Iterator;
>   java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   SampleSuite$$anonfun$2$$anon$3.document$PunctuationRemover$$super$source()Lscala/collection/Iterator;

I referenced this post but I think my situation is a little different
[Can I override a scala class method with a method from a trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5776449/can-i-override-a-scala-class-method-with-a-method-from-a-trait)

Comment: Usually you get a much faster response if you have code segments that compile up to the point where you get the compilation error. Allowing someone to easily reproduce the error makes it much more likely for you to get an answer.

Comment: I plugged your code into the IntelliJ IDE and it compiled without complaint.  I'm unable to reproduce the error.